# JavaScript/PHP file uploader

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, ajax, file

I'm writing a JavaScript/PHP file uploader and I want to start this project off on the right track. I've started with this, a JavaScript `Uploader` object which will handle Ajax calls, display progress, show error messages, etc. I'm just hoping to get some feedback on the way I'm setting up my scripts.

```
function Uploader(method) {

if(arguments.callee._singleton) return arguments.callee._singleton;
var _this = arguments.callee._singleton = this;

_this.opts = {
    form:"#uploader",
    filePath:"public/uploads/",
    errorCodes:{
        1:"No file/folder selected",
        2:"Invalid file/folder type",
        3:"File/folder exceeds upload size"
    }   
}

_this.methods = {

    init: function(options) {
        for(var o in options) {
            _this.opts[o] = options[o];
        }

        _this.methods.setup();
    },

    setup: function() {

    }

}   

if(_this.methods[method]) return _this.methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
else if(typeof method === "object" || !method) return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);

}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how exactly you'll be using this `Uploader` object? The `_singleton` code at the very top and the code at the very bottom (as well as the use of a local `_this` variable) is confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use an existing ajax file upload library, like [Fine Uploader](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader)?

As for your code.

## 1)

I think you meant to return `_this.methods.init.apply(this, arguments);`.

## 2)

You should rewrite Uploader to not use `arguments.callee` for two reasons; it makes your code harder to read and for the browser to optimize.

Comment: Not to mention `arguments.callee` isn't supported in ECMAScript 5.